# How can I detect when a user touches something other than a menu or it's children?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, touch

I'm trying to write some JavaScript to handle touch interactions on a drop down menu. This is working well, except that I can't figure out how to hide the menu when a user taps away from it.

My script is as follows:

```
// mark all menu items as inative
function mark_all_inactive(elem) {
    elem.find(".is-active").removeClass("is-active");
    elem.find("[aria-hidden=false]").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
}

// mark element as active
function mark_active(elem) {
    elem.closest(".menu-list_item").addClass("is-active");
    elem.siblings("[aria-hidden]").attr("aria-hidden", "false");
}

// open on touchstart
jQuery(".menu-list_item").not(".menu-list_item.-mega .menu-list_item.-parent").on("touchstart", function(e) {
    if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("is-active") && jQuery(this).children("[aria-hidden]").length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mark_all_inactive(jQuery(this).closest(".menu-list"));
        mark_active(jQuery(this).children(".menu-list_link"));
    }
});

// hide on focusout
jQuery(".menu-list").on("focusout", ".menu-list_link", function() {
    var parent_item = jQuery(this).closest(".menu-list_item.-parent.is-active");

    if (parent_item.length) {
        // timeout required for the next element to get focus
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!parent_item.find(":focus").length) {
                parent_item.removeClass("is-active");
                parent_item.children("[aria-hidden]").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
                parent_item.closest(".menu-list_item.-parent.is-active").find(".menu-list_link").first().trigger("focusout");
            }
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm using `touchstart` to add some classes, which works perfectly. The issue arises when trying to remove those classes.

The `focusout` bit of code is primarily used for keyboard navigation, but I'd like to adapt it to also trigger when you tap away from the menu.

From what I understand, mobile browsers typically don't fire `focusout` when tapping away from something. That seems odd to me, as you'd think tapping away from something would surly fire a `focusout` regardless of input type, but that's beside the point.

I have looked in to `touchend`, but that appears to fire immediately after lifting your finger, which isn't what I want. The goal is to tap once to add the classes, then be able to lift your finger to select a child link (which can also contain flyout menus, thus re-using the same `touchstart` script). Then, when you tap anywhere that's not the active menu, remove the classes.

So, on to the question: Can the `focusout` bit of script be modified to accommodate tapping away from a menu or it's children? If not, how would I go about writing a second bit of script to accomplish that task?

You can view a live demo at the follow URL:

https://framework.ghostlyco.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, but I don't know that it's the best way. It seems kind of dumb to attach an event to the entire document, but this works:

```
// hide on touch away
jQuery(document).on("touchstart", function(e) {
    if (!jQuery(e.target).closest(".menu-list_item.-parent.is-active").length) {
        jQuery(".menu-list_item.-parent.is-active").children("[aria-hidden]").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
        jQuery(".menu-list_item.-parent.is-active").removeClass("is-active");
    }
});
```